# How to manage badge on bottom navigation bar?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I will try to explain my question. I have an app with chat on it.You can move through app with a bottom nav bar(it have 5 items, chat page is one of them). I am able to show a badge in list chat item when a new unread message comes. I want to show a badge in bootom nav chat item too. How can I do it? I have flutter bloc cubit as management state. I do not post any code because I am not sure which one will help to solve this, ask for it if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the child of the `BottomNavigationBarItem` with a `BlocBuilder` and update the widget as you see fit based on the state. You'll need to share your bottom nav code and the bloc code if you want specific examples.